# Vuex store to return object results from firebase not working

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuex

I can not for the life of me figure out why this isn't working so hoping you might be able to assist

All I am trying to do is a get request via a vuex store instead of in my component as I currently do as part of my learning vue/nuxt, but just can't get it to work as follows, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong please

vex store

```
import Vuex from "vuex";
import axios from "axios";
const URL = 'MYPATH';
const logStore = () => {
return new Vuex.Store({

state: {
  logItems: {}
},

actions: {

  setLog ({ commit }) {
    axios
      .get('URL')
      .then(r => r.data)
      .then(logItems => {
        console.log(logItems) // I am getting back my results in log here
        })
      .then(logItems => {
      commit('logItems', logItems)
    })
  }, 
},

mutations: {
  logItems (state, logItems) {
    state.logItems = logItems
  },

getters: {
    logItems(state) {
        return state.logItems // log console here is empty object
      }
},

});
};
```

export default logStore;

In my component I have

```
    import { mapState } from 'vuex'

 created () {
    this.$store.dispatch('setLog', this.logItems)
    console.log(this.$store.getters.logItems) // empty object here
    },
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting my results back to my action but not into my getter or component

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to return your `logItems` here so the next `then` has access to it

```
.then(logItems => {
    console.log(logItems) // I am getting back my results in log here
    return logItems;
})
```

When you use without curly braces, whatever you have in the function body is automatically returned, like you have here

```
.then(r => r.data)
```

However, when you do use curly braces, if you need the next function in the chain to get a value, you need to return it and get it in the next function

```
.then(logItems => {
    console.log(logItems)
    return logItems
})
.then(thisWillBeTheReturnAbove => { // ... code ... })
```

---

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments, I created a GitLab repository with an example that you can find here http://gitlab.com/vitorleite/vue-firebase-todo.

You should be able to clone it and run it locally by doing `npm install` and `npm run serve`, you'll need to change `store.js` to include your Firebase endpoint. I did leave the one I used in a comment, but I'll change the permissions to be `read-only` at some point.

I created the project using [@vue/cli 3.0](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli) and used the sample JsFiddle Vue Todo code as a base.